# MS SQL Script to find rows where value does not exist

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have a situation where I have in one table record 'a' which have order number 0 and also record 'a' but with order number 1 - this is correct.

i also have record 'b' which has order number 1 and there is no row for record 'b' where order number = 0. - this is not correct.

I need to create a script which will find all records where order number = 1 but order number 0 doesn't exist. Can you guys help with this?
i cannot use simple:
SELECT DISTINCT record FROM tablename WHERE order_number <> 0

because it will give me also record 'a' which i don't want to have in results.

I was thinking about using Not Exists function but it always compares 2 tables where i have all records in one table.

Regards

Comment: Your title says MS SQL, the tags say `mysql`. Which is it?

Comment: my mistake, corrected. thanks!

Comment: You should add the tag for the correct database, e.g. `sql-server-2008` if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Not In`in `Where` will eliminate 'a' and will give only 'b'

Try this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT record FROM tablename WHERE order_number <> 0
and record not in (Select record from tablename WHERE order_number = 0);
```

hope this helps:-)